# How can i show my toggle plugin on the first loading

Tags: javascript

I use a little plugin and i just want to always show my panel.
If i click on "Show" i will see the panel (i can toggle it's fine) but i would like to see the panel on the first load directely . (No need to clcik on the button).

http://www.project-heberg.fr/CREAZ/menu/

```
<script>
            var menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
                showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
                body = document.body;

            function init()
            {

            }
            init()

            showRight.onclick = function() {
                classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
                classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
                disableOther( 'showRight' );
            };

            function disableOther( button ) {
                if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
                    classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: It's an API . i will answer my post for showing you classie.js

Answer (score 0):

This is classie.js

```
 /*!
     * classie - class helper functions
     * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
     * 
     * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
     * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
     * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
     * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
     */

    /*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */

    ( function( window ) {

    'use strict';

    // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

    function classReg( className ) {
      return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
    }

    // classList support for class management
    // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
    var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

    if ( 'classList' in document.documentElement ) {
      hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
        return elem.classList.contains( c );
      };
      addClass = function( elem, c ) {
        elem.classList.add( c );
      };
      removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
        elem.classList.remove( c );
      };
    }
    else {
      hasClass = function( elem, c ) {
        return classReg( c ).test( elem.className );
      };
      addClass = function( elem, c ) {
        if ( !hasClass( elem, c ) ) {
          elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
        }
      };
      removeClass = function( elem, c ) {
        elem.className = elem.className.replace( classReg( c ), ' ' );
      };
    }

    function toggleClass( elem, c ) {
      var fn = hasClass( elem, c ) ? removeClass : addClass;
      fn( elem, c );
    }

    window.classie = {
      // full names
      hasClass: hasClass,
      addClass: addClass,
      removeClass: removeClass,
      toggleClass: toggleClass,
      // short names
      has: hasClass,
      add: addClass,
      remove: removeClass,
      toggle: toggleClass
    };

    })( window );
```